# Groupby a data set in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 30 years of daily data. I want to calculate average daily over 30 years. For example, I have data like this

```
1/1/2036      0
1/2/2036    73.61180115
1/3/2036    73.77733612
1/4/2036    73.61183929
1/5/2036    73.75443268
1/6/2036    73.58483887
.........
12/22/2065  73.90600586
12/23/2065  74.38092804
12/24/2065  77.76309967
```

I want to calculate:

```
1/1/yyyy     ?
1/2/yyyy     ?
1/3/yyyy     ?
......
12/30/yyyy   ?
12/31/yyyy   ?
```

I wrote a code in python but it's only calculating 1st month avg. My dataset is 10950 x 1 which will be converted to 365 x 1. Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

files=glob.glob('*2036-2065*rcp26*.csv*')
RO_act=pd.read_csv('Reservoir storage zones_sohom.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
for i, fl in enumerate(files):
    df = pd.read_csv(fl, index_col=0,usecols=[0,78],parse_dates=True)
    df1=df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')).mean()
```

Please help

Comment: It is not clear which average you want. Do you want the average of all the date, or the average of each year/month separately?

Comment: Average of a day for 30 years. For example: 1st Jan 2036, 1st Jan 2037....1st Jan 2065 will be one avg!

Comment: What is the type of your indices?

Comment: Index: datetime64 (2040-06-26 00:00:00); Indices are in dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to `df.groupby` which will act on the indices to make the groups. So, for you, use:

```
df.groupby(lambda x: (x.day,x.month)).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following series `s`

```
days = pd.date_range('1986-01-01', '2015-12-31')
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(len(days)), days)
```

then what you're looking for is:

```
s.groupby([s.index.month, s.index.day]).mean()
```

---

#### Timing

@juanpa.arrivillaga's answer gives the same solution but is slower.

[image]